# Question on proof of Heine-Borel theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Spivak's book on calculus on manifolds has a statement that I can't grasp. Say we have the closed interval $[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$ covered by $\mathcal{O}$ and we define $$A=\{x \in [a,b]:[a,x] \textrm{ is covered by a finite number of subsets in }\mathcal{O}\}$$
Clearly, $A$ is bounded above by $b$. Say $\alpha$ is the least upper bound of $A$. Then $\alpha\in U$ for some open set $U$ in $\mathcal{O}$. Since $U$ is an open set, then there most be some interval of points smaller than $\alpha$ contained in $U$. What I don't understand is that Spivak states that since $\alpha$ is the least upper bound of $A$, there must be some $x$ in this interval (to the left of $\alpha$ and contained in $U$) that is in $A$. Can somebody help me understand why this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\alpha$ is the least upper bound of $A$, if we take $\beta <\alpha$, this means that $\beta$ is not an upper bound of $A$, i.e. there exists $x\in A$ such that $\beta<x≤\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

As a consequence of the definition of least upper bound, given any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $x \in A$ with $0 <\alpha - x \leq \varepsilon$.  Otherwise, $\alpha - \varepsilon$ would be an upper bound of $A$, contradicting the fact that $\alpha$ is the least upper bound.

By openness of $U$, choose $\varepsilon > 0$ so that $[\alpha-\varepsilon, \alpha + \varepsilon] \cap [a,b]  \subset U$. Then choose $x$ as described above.